# Node-exporter is not running on 3 nodes of the cluster

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, prometheus-node-exporter

I run node-exporter as a daemonset inside AWS EKS and found today that it's present on 10 nodes, however my cluster has 13 nodes.

How do I make sure it also runs on 3 missed nodes?

Comment: Well, are your nodes tainted? how are those 3 nodes different?

Comment: @Rico - yes these nodes are tainted, but my DaemonSet deploying the node-exporter pods has no "tolerations" section. So that is the reason?

Comment: correct, you should tolerate daemonset like ```tolerations: 
      - effect: NoSchedule
        operator: Exists```

Comment: @MaxLobur so without having *key* defined in the tolerations section. I.e. "An empty key with operator Exists matches all keys, values and effects which means this will tolerate everything."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tolerate the daemonset using:

```
tolerations:        
  - effect: NoSchedule         
    operator: Exists
```

Per [Docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/taint-and-toleration/) DeamonSets already have a few tolerations by default. The no-key one I posted is making sure you are covering all possible reasons of `NoSchedule`:

> An empty key with operator Exists matches all keys, values and effects
> which means this will tolerate everything.

This is a commonly used setting for monitoring daemons and log collectors.

Comment: Removing the effect: NoSchedule works better (more node coverage) in my case.